# SQL Query Novice Looking for Some Direction

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm new to SQL and I'm working on a project where I'm querying data from various tables of a database. The key component of the queried information is a series of permit IDs. These IDs are 12 alphanumeric digits and end with a 0 if they are new permits or end with a 1-9 if they are revised permits (the previous 11 digits still match the initial permit ID that was revised). Additionally, if a permit is cancelled, a 13th character, "C", is appended to the ID. My basic query in pseudo-SQL looks something like this:

```
SELECT Permit_ID,
[other related data, things like permit holder name, issue date, etc.]
...
FROM Premit_Table
inner Join [other appropriate tables]
WHERE Permit_ID is not null
ORDER BY Permit_ID
```

After this query I will have a table of data that would look something like this:

```
    Initial Permit_ID     [Other Data]  ......

    XXXXXXXXXXX0               - 

    YYYYYYYYYYY0               -

    YYYYYYYYYYY1               -

    YYYYYYYYYYY2               -

    ZZZZZZZZZZZ0C              -

    ZZZZZZZZZZZ1C              -
```

What I would like to do is change my query to group together some of the revised permit information with the initial permit which they were derived from. I want the final product to look something like this:

```
    Initial Permit_ID        [Initial Permit_ID Data]......   Revised Permit_ID      [Select Revised Permit_ID Data] ......
    XXXXXXXXXXX0                        -                         [No Data]                      [No Data]
    YYYYYYYYYYY0                        -                        YYYYYYYYYYY1                        -
    YYYYYYYYYYY0                        -                        YYYYYYYYYYY2                        -
    ZZZZZZZZZZZ0C                       -                       ZZZZZZZZZZZ1C                        -
```

The final 2 columns are what I want to produce for my final table. In this set up, I want to have the initial ID displayed along with any additional data, plus if there has been any revision to the permit I want to display the new ID along with some select information (things that have changed, such as the re-issue date) in the same row. If more than one revision has been made, I want one row per revision with the initial ID data displayed on all rows. This same model holds true for any permits that have been cancelled (denoted by the "C").

I have very little exposure to SQL thus far and I'm a little lost on how to restructure my query to produce the desired results. I would appreciate being pointed in the right direction.

Comment: So, the initial `Permit_ID` ends with a `0`?

Comment: Yes, when a new permit is issued and added to the DB it always ends with a 0. Any revisions to the permit iterates the final digit by 1 (up until it hits 9 which is the max allowed). These revised permits are added to the DB as new entries with their own set of data (much of it is identical to the initial permit, but some of it is changed). If a permit is cancelled, a "C" is added to the end of all versions of that permit's ID.

Comment: You have `ZZZZZZZZZZZ0C`, does this mean that the initial has been cancelled and then its revisions (`ZZZZZZZZZZZ1C`) therefore are also cancelled?

Comment: I don't handle the actual permits on the front end, I only have access to the DB, but from my observations when a permit is cancelled, all related IDs are cancelled as well. So if XXXXXXXXXXX1 was the most current version of a permit and that permit got cancelled, the DB would update the entries for that permit to XXXXXXXXXXX1C, as well as XXXXXXXXXXX0C since it is an older version of the same permit.

Answer (score 0):

Separate first the initial permits from the revised permits. Then you can do a `LEFT JOIN`.

```
CREATE TABLE Permit_Table(Permit_ID VARCHAR(13))
INSERT INTO Permit_Table VALUES
('XXXXXXXXXXX0'), ('YYYYYYYYYYY0'), ('YYYYYYYYYYY1'),
('YYYYYYYYYYY2'), ('ZZZZZZZZZZZ0C'), ('ZZZZZZZZZZZ1C');

;WITH Initial AS( -- Inital Permit_ID ends with 0 or 0C
    SELECT *
    FROM Permit_Table
    WHERE 
        Permit_ID LIKE '%0'
        OR Permit_ID LIKE '%0C'
)
,Revised AS( -- Revised Permit_ID ends with [1-9] or [1-9]C
    SELECT 
        *,
        Inital_Permit_ID = -- Get the initial Permit_ID using some string manipulation
            CASE
                WHEN RIGHT(Permit_ID, 1) LIKE '%[1-9]' THEN SUBSTRING(Permit_ID, 1, 11) + '0'
                WHEN RIGHT(Permit_ID, 1) = 'C' THEN SUBSTRING(Permit_ID, 1, 11) + '0C'
            END
    FROM Permit_Table
    WHERE 
        Permit_ID LIKE '%[1-9]'
        OR Permit_ID LIKE '%[1-9]C'
)
SELECT
    [Initial Permit_ID] = i.Permit_ID,
    [Revised Permit_ID] = r.Permit_ID
FROM Initial i
LEFT JOIN Revised r
    ON i.Permit_ID = r.Inital_Permit_ID

DROP TABLE Permit_Table
```

**RESULT**

```
Initial Permit_ID Revised Permit_ID
----------------- -----------------
XXXXXXXXXXX0      NULL
YYYYYYYYYYY0      YYYYYYYYYYY1
YYYYYYYYYYY0      YYYYYYYYYYY2
ZZZZZZZZZZZ0C     ZZZZZZZZZZZ1C
```